# Get configured S3 bucket for detailed billing reports in aws with python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-billing

I would like to query with python and boto3 the configured s3 bucket for the detailed billing reports inside the aws account. There is the command [describe_report_definitions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cur.html#CostandUsageReportService.Client.describe_report_definitions) listed inside the boto3 docs which should return the available reports with the configured s3 bucket. When I run the following code I receive all the time an empty array as response although a s3 bucket is configured an reports are available.

```
    cur_client = boto3.client(
            'cur',
            'us-east-1'
    )

    cur_describe_report_definitions_response = cur_client.describe_report_definitions()
    print(str(json.dumps(cur_describe_report_definitions_response['ReportDefinitions'])))

    #Response
    []
```

The goal is to get the configured s3 bucket name.
[image]

Comment: The bucket doesn't change, why would you need to get the bucket name programmatically? What's your use-case?

Comment: I need to collect the generated reports inside this buckets over multiple accounts. So it would be more convenient to read out the bucket name automatically.

Comment: You can't use AWS organizations? Using one consolidated account to manage those accounts?

Comment: We use this but there are more than one organization.

Comment: just print the response, why do you need json.dumps? or `cur_describe_report_definitions_response['ReportDefinitions']['S3Bucket']`

Comment: As I wrote in the post: I receive all the time an empyt array as response. Therefore if I would print `cur_describe_report_definitions_response['ReportDefinitions']['S3Bucket']` there would be an error that the key 'S3Bucket' does not exists inside the 'ReportDefinitions'.